# js / css flip card game bug in shuffle function

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a js memory game. It has a 24-card grid, and it is supposed to shuffle randomly out of a deck of 15 cards in order to create a little variety. The game should be different every time. However, at random the game shuffles the initial deck and builds the board with 11 pairs and one non-pair of cards. Here's the whole js file:

```
`var score;
var cardsmatched;
var ui = $("#gameUI");
var uiIntro =$("#gameIntro");
var uiStats = $("#  gameStats");
var uiComplete = $("#gameComplete");
var uiCards = $("#cards");
var uiScore = $(".gameScore");
var uiReset = $(".gameReset");
var uiPlay = $("#gamePlay");
var uiTimer = $("#timer");

var matchingGame = {};
matchingGame.deck = ['grilledfish', 'grilledfish','barbacoa', 'barbacoa','tripa', 'tripa','bajafish', 'bajafish','carneasada', 'carneasada','carnitas', 'carnitas', 'chorizoasado','chorizoasado','shrimptaco','shrimptaco','decabeza','decabeza','alpastor', 'alpastor','dorados','dorados', 'lengua','lengua','chicharron','chicharron','sudados','sudados', 'polloasado','polloasado',];

$(function(){
    init();
});

function init() {
                uiComplete.hide();
                uiCards.hide();
                playGame = false;
                uiPlay.click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    uiIntro.hide();
                    startGame();
                });

                uiReset.click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                uiComplete.hide();
                reStartGame();

            });
}

function startGame(){
        uiTimer.show();
        uiScore.html("0 seconds");
        uiStats.show();
        uiCards.show();
        score = 0;
        cardsmatched= 0;
        if (playGame == false) {
            playGame = true;
                matchingGame.deck.sort(shuffle);
                for (var i=0; i<25; i++){
                    $(".card:first-child").clone().appendTo("#cards");
                } 
                uiCards.children().each(function(index) {
                    $(this).css({
                        "left" : ($(this).width() + 20) * (index % 6),
                        "top" : ($(this).height() + 20) * Math.floor(index / 6)
                    });
                    var pattern = matchingGame.deck.pop();
                    $(this).find(".back").addClass(pattern);
                    $(this).attr("data-pattern",pattern);
                    $(this).click(selectCard);
                });
            timer();
        };
}
 function timer(){
     if (playGame){
         scoreTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
             uiScore.html(++score = "seconds");
             timer();
         }, 1000);
     };
 };

function shuffle() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
}

function selectCard(){
    if($(".card-flipped").size()> 1){
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass("card-flipped");
    if($(".card-flipped").size() == 2) {
        setTimeout(checkPattern, 1000);
    };
};

function checkPattern(){
    if (isMatchPattern()) {
        $(".card-flipped").removeClass("card-flipped").addClass("card-removed");
        if(document.webkitTransitionEnd){
            $(".card-removed").bind("webkitTransitionEnd", removeTookCards);
        }else{ 
            removeTookCards();
    } else {
        $(".card-flipped").removeClass("card-flipped");

        }

    }

    function isMatchPattern(){
        var cards = $(".card-flipped");
        var pattern = $(cards[0]).data("pattern");
        var anotherPattern = $(cards[1]).data("pattern");
        return (pattern == anotherPattern);

    }

    function removeTookCards() {
        if (cardsmatched < 12) {
            cardsmatched++;
            $(".card-removed").remove();
        }else{
            $(".card-removed").remove();
            uiCards.hide();
            uiComplete.show();
            clearTimeout(scoreTimeout);

        }
        }

function reStartGame(){
        playGame = false;
        uiCards.html("<div class='card'><div class='face front'></div><div class='face back'></div></div>");
        clearTimeout(scoreTimeout);
        matchingGame.deck = ['grilledfish', 'grilledfish','barbacoa', 'barbacoa','tripa', 'tripa','bajafish', 'bajafish','carneasada', 'carneasada','carnitas', 'carnitas', 'chorizoasado','chorizoasado','shrimptaco','shrimptaco','decabeza','decabeza','alpastor', 'alpastor','dorados','dorados', 'lengua','lengua','chicharron','chicharron','sudados','sudados', 'polloasado','polloasado',];
        startGame();
}

`
```

Comment: You've not included your `shuffle` function, can you please update your question to include it?

Comment: Maybe you're not re-initializing matchingGame.deck?? pop will remove values from the array. Can you post more code?

Comment: i added the whole js file, thank you

Comment: There are a few syntax errors in here when I try to run it, you might want to fix those first.